# Why complete command can't store previously set words?

Tags: autocomplete

I'm using `complete` command for adding auto complete for my script. For example I want to add `boogh` for my script `my_script`

```
$complete -W "boogh" my_script
```

After running this command, `boogh` keyword will appear easily after pressing tab key. But the problem is after a short time (about an hour or so) or after reboot, `boogh` keyword would be forgotten.

I was wondering whether anyone could help me with the problem i.e. telling me how complete command stores custom added words or is there any way that I can make the added word permanently stored in the system OR whether I am not running the command properly.

P.S: I've already read manual for `complete` command couldn't be  able to find any conflict with the way I'm using it.

Edit: I'm using both Ubuntu 16.04 server and 18.04 server.

Comment: Which distro are you using? See if you can add it to `/etc/bash_completion.d/`

Comment: Did you start another shell? (I don't think it is a timer, it is like most things they happen in time, but it not time that cased them.)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Me neither. Apparently it can't be some time dependent thing. And also I didn't start a new shell.